# Delay container restart

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using a ReplicationController to create a pod running redis container.

The redis container is monitored by Redis Sentinel.  And there is a problem, if redis crashed and restart too fast, it may cause trouble to Redis Sentinel when the voting is in progress.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "ReplicationController",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "redis",
    "labels": { "name" : "redis" }
  },
  "spec": {  
    "replicas": 1,
    "selector": {
      "name":"redis"
    },
    "template": { 
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "name":"redis"
        }
      },
      "spec": { 
        "volumes": [
            //...
        ],
        "containers": [
          //...
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Would it be possible to delay the restart ? i.e.  Restart the container after 60 seconds from last crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubelet already backs off container restarts automatically. In that case, you'll see something like the following:

`$ cluster/kubectl.sh get pods
NAME                   READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
...
mem-besteffort-zpnpm   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   4          3m`

If you find that it restarts the containers too frequently, you could do something as simple as sleep 60 before executing the actual command.

Answer (score 1):

Better alternatives to `sleep`:

1. `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: test
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
        spec:
            containers:
              - name: test
                image: ...
            terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
```

2. [preStop handler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers), read more about [lifecycle hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks)

Read also: [Kubernetes best practices: terminating with grace](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace)